# npm test differs from manual execution

Tags: node.js, npm

In my `package.json` I have the the following;

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "NODE_ENV=test mocha **/*.spec.js"
}
```

When I run `npm test` it only completes one test within my sub directories.

```
# npm test

sample test
  ✓ single task

1 passing
```

But when I run the script manually in my console it completes all the tests.

```
# NODE_ENV=test mocha **/*.spec.js

sample test
  ✓ single task

sample test x2
  ✓ single task x1
  ✓ single task x2
  ✓ single task x3
  ✓ single task x4
  ✓ single task x5

sample test x3
  ✓ single task x1
  ✓ single task x2
  ✓ single task x3
  ✓ single task x4
  ✓ single task x5
  ✓ single task x6

sample test x4
  ✓ single task x1
  ✓ single task x2
  ✓ single task x3
  ✓ single task x4


16 passing (15s)
```

Why is there a difference when its the same command being run? and how do I get `npm test` to run all my tests?

Comment: Is `mocha` in your `devDependencies`? What happens if you change the commands to simply be `mocha --version` both in your terminal and in the `test` script? Do the versions differ? I am guessing they do. Possibly one of them is buggy. To force an update of the local copy of `mocha`, make sure `devDependencies` has the latest version, then do `rm -rf node_modules && npm cache clean && npm install`

Comment: `mocha` version is the same in both `npm` and manual. `3.2.0`.
Had already tried to re-install mocha. I did it again with your commands just to be sure, same thing. Still only one test run.

Comment: Are you on Windows by any chance? What terminal program are you running and which shell (try `echo $0`)? Is the `NODE_ENV` really important to your code? If that environment variable wasn't being set or exported correctly, what would you expect to happen? I am also curious what will happen if you change the glob pattern to something like `NODE_ENV=test mocha test/*.spec.js` (non-recursive file wildcard). It seems to have something to do with globbing.

Comment: I removed NODE_ENV and it didn't make a difference. Running on Mac, using ZSH plugin on top of the normal Mac terminal window. If I remove the recursive it will go through one folder and work,  `mocha services/user/*.spec.js` and `npm test`. So looks like something to do with the recursive search?

Comment: Looks like the wildcard search was the problem. I just changed the test script in `package.json` to : `mocha **/**/*.spec.js` and it works. Will have to see if it picks up tests in all subfolders or not, but so far is running through all existing tests.

Comment: You shouldn't need that extra `**/`. See my full answer for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue, caused by the syntax that mocha uses for [globbing](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob), which conflicts with the globbing system of the shell itself on many machines. And if you are not careful, the shell will evaluate and expand it first before mocha even has a chance to see it.

- [#1175 - Mocha aliased via `npm test` fails to glob all files](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/1175)
- [#1115 - Documentation around glob patterns and shell expansion](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/1115)

The solution is to tell your shell to treat the pattern as a string literal, by wrapping it in quotes. Single quotes are best on *nix systems. If you need Windows support you will have to resort to [escaped double quotes](http://blog.jonasbandi.net/2016/04/crossplatform-npm.html), which has some pitfalls on *nix.

```
NODE_ENV=test mocha '**/*.spec.js'
```

You will still need to make sure the pattern matches files properly. But using this technique will fix the inconsistent behavior. The difference in behavior is caused by the way `npm` wraps your `test` script and runs it.

Ways to help:

- File a [glob issue](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob/issues) to discuss shell compatibility.
- Contribute a PR to [mocha's documentation](https://github.com/mochajs/mochajs.github.io/issues/8) to raise awareness.

Note that other CLI tools that rely upon [glob](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob), such as [eslint](https://github.com/eslint/eslint), are also susceptible to this problem and the workaround applies to them as well.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the answer.